# How to store NSDate to DATETIME with **TIME ZONE**?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, datetime, nsdate

How to format the date string to get the **timezone** information stored in a MySQL DATETIME field? Does DATETIME store timezone information at all?

Comment: This is NOT A DUPLICATE, since question focuses on TIMEZONE storage.

Comment: Anyway, answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, neither `DATETIME` nor `TIMESTAMP` data types store tz data.

`TIMESTAMP` values are translated from the current session time zone to UTC upon storage, and translated back to the current session time zone.

What's the current session time zone?  Read this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: So I have to open a new field for timezone, if I want to save timezoned date for a particular event.